# How to link WSIG GUI to jUDDI

Tags: agents-jade, juddi

**Here is what I already did :**

I created a 10 jade agents, each agent publish its own Web Service After lunching JADE Remote Agent Management GUI and Lunching jUDDI I get the screen bellow.

[image: jade screenshot]

I used the WSIG add-on to publish the Web Services like the screenshot bellow.

[image: WSIG GUI]

then I went to jUDDI admin and created a publisher with username bob and password bob, logged as bob in the jUDDI User Interface and created a Business entity and tModel Partition (Key generator) based on jUDDI V3.

after doing the step above I went to *wsig.properties* file that lives inside the deployed wsig web application under *wsig/conf/wsig.properties*.

added the jUDDI config to the file as the screenshot bellow shows :

[image: WSIG GUI showing config]

everything I did is good as far as I know based on the WSIG Guide.

**My Questions :**

why the WSIG doesn't publish the Services in the jUDDI ?
Have I done something wrong ? where ?

Note: I see error in the console of tomcat screenshot bellow.

[image: wsig error]

Answer (score 0):

the solution to the above problem is very simple the **wsig.properties** have a missing config item which is :

> **uddi.tmodel.key=your tmodel key created in the jUDDI User Interface**